# Find odd primes $p$ and $q$ such that $(p-1)\mid {3q-1}$ and $(q-1)\mid{3p-1}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, divisibility

> Find odd primes $p$ and $q$ such that $(p-1)\mid {3q-1}$ and $(q-1)\mid{3p-1}$.

My progress till now: I got $p=11$ and $q=17$ as a solution satisfying this question.
Can anyone give me some hints rather than a solution ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: There are also some smaller ones...  Are you supposed to find **all** the solutions, or is it enough to find one (in which case you are already done)?

Comment: oh , yes.. I meant odd primes

Comment: @RobertIsrael I am supposed to find all the solutions .

Comment: $3$ and $3$, $3$ and $5$.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h39774p257111

Comment: @RobertIsrael , thanks ( I actually didn't think about p=q )

Comment: @Adola thanks for sharing the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition tells us that $\frac{3p-1}{q-1}$,$\frac{3q-1}{p-1}$, and $\frac{3p-1}{p-1} \frac{3q-1}{q-1}$ is an integer. However, for $p,q\ge5$, we have

$$\frac{3p-1}{p-1} \frac{3q-1}{q-1} < \frac{3p}{\frac{4}{5}p} \times \frac{3q}{\frac{4}{5}q} <15$$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint: When you have a problem like this, with two separate divisibilities, you want to make the right sides look the same. In particular, here
$$p-1|3q-1+3(p-1)=3p+3q-4,$$
and $q-1$ must also divide this by symmetry. As a result,
$$\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)|3p+3q-4.$$
The left side should be larger than the right side for most $(p,q)$ as long as $p-1$ and $q-1$ can't share big factors, which would allow you to finish; can you determine whether $p-1$ and $q-1$ can share large factors?

Comment: I am sorry, but can you explain this line? "  for most (,) as long as −1 and −1 can't share big factors,"

Comment: If you can show that $p-1$ and $q-1$ have few common factors (say, can only have factors bounded by $k$), then $\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)\geq \frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{k}$, and the left side is too large compared to the right.

Answer (score 3):

Let $3q-1 = k(p-1)$.  Try $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ until you can show $k$ is too large.

Comment: but q  is not fixed , so how can we show that k is too large ..

Comment: Let's say $q \le p$.  $$k = \frac{3q-1}{p-1} \le \frac{3p-1}{p-1} = 3 + \frac{2}{p-1}.$$  How big can this be?